# Showing the same content in the every cells while scrolling the cells

Tags: ios

I have 5 types of tableview cells.And i ave one basecell.

BaseCell:-

import UIKit

```
class BaseCell: UITableViewCell {
    // MARK: Internal Properties
    var type: CellType!
    var textChangedBlock: ((String) -> Void)?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    func setOptions(Options1:NH_OptionsModel){}
    func setOptions(OptionsSelected:NH_OptionsModel){}
    func setOptions1(OptionsSelected:NH_OptionsModel){}
    func setOptions(OptionsisSelected:NH_OptionsModel){}
    func setOptions1(OptionsisSelected:NH_OptionsModel){}

}
```

One Tableviewcell:-

```
class RadioTypeCell:  BaseCell {
    var actionBlock: (() -> Void)?
    @IBOutlet weak var optionLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonType: UIButton?

    override func setOptions(Options1:NH_OptionsModel) {
      self.optionLabel?.text = Options1.values
    }

    override func setOptions1(OptionsSelected:NH_OptionsModel) {
        self.buttonType?.isHidden = false
        buttonType?.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "radio_check.png"), for: .normal)

        print(OptionsSelected.isSelected)
        OptionsSelected.isSelected = true
        print(OptionsSelected.isSelected) 
    }

     override func setOptions(OptionsisSelected:NH_OptionsModel) {   
        self.buttonType?.isHidden = false
        buttonType?.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "radio_uncheck.png"), for: .normal)

        print(OptionsisSelected.isSelected)

        OptionsisSelected.isSelected = false
        print(OptionsisSelected.isSelected) 
    }

    @IBAction func onActionButton(btn: UIButton) {
        print("click the cell")
        actionBlock?()
    }

     override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }   

}
```

In viewcontroller:-

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let model = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.section)
        print(model.answerType)

        print(model.answerType?.rawValue)

        let c = model.answerType
        let cellClass = c?.cellType().getClass()
        print(cellClass)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: (cellClass?.cellReuseIdentifier())!, for: indexPath) as! BaseCell
        print(cell)

        let optionModel = questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
        cell.setOptions(Options1: optionModel)

        cell.type = c?.cellType()
        currentCell(c: cell, index: indexPath.row)
        return cell
    }
```

So In the tableview cell ,it contain
the following things.
1.One button
2.Label(Here showing the options)
So while selecting the one option i will click on the button,at that time the button has set the background image.Initially the image will be radio button with uncheck after while clicking the button the button image becomes radio button check.

And i given the code in the didselect the cell from the tableview.
Now my problem is after selecting the cells and then scrolling the tableview .The cells content is not refreshing .How to solve the problem.
And my tableview has sections.

My model:-

```
import UIKit
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]

enum AnswerType:Int
{
    case CheckBoxCell = 1
    case RadioTypeCell

    case SmileyTypeCell
    case StarRatingTypeCell
    case TextTypeCell

    func cellType() -> CellType{
        switch self {
        case .CheckBoxCell: return .checkboxtype
        case .RadioTypeCell :return .radiotype

        case .SmileyTypeCell: return .smileytype
        case .StarRatingTypeCell: return .starratingtype
        case  .TextTypeCell: return .textfieldtype
        default: return .radiotype
        }
    }



}
class QuestionListModel: NSObject {

    var dataListArray33:[NH_OptionsModel] = []


    var id:Int!
    var question:String!
    var buttontype:String!
    var options:[String]?
    var v:String?
    var answerType:NHAnswerType?


      var optionsModelArray:[OptionsModel] = []
    init(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

        guard   let question = dictionary["question"] as? String,
            let typebutton = dictionary["button_type"] as? String,

                let id = dictionary["id"] as? Int
             else {
                return

        }

        self.answerType = AnswerType(rawValue: Int(typebutton)!)

        if let options = dictionary["options"] as? [String]{
            print(options)

           print(options)


            for values in options{

                print(values)

                let optionmodel = OptionsModel(values: values)
                self.optionsModelArray.append(optionmodel)

            }


        }


        self.buttontype = typebutton
        self.question = question
        self.id = id

                   }

}
```

my viewmodel:-

```
 var OptionListArray:Array<OptionsModel>? = []

    init(withdatasource  newDatasourceModel:QuestionDataSourceModel,withmodel model:HomeModel) {
        datasourceModel = newDatasourceModel
        homemodel1 = model
         print(homemodel1)


        print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)
    }

    func numberOfSections() -> Int{
        print((datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!)
        return (datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!
    }

    func titleForHeaderInSection(atsection section: Int) -> QuestionListModel {
        return datasourceModel.dataListArray![section]
    }

    func numberOfRowsIn(section:Int) -> Int {

        print( datasourceModel.dataListArray?[section].optionsModelArray.count ?? 0)
        return datasourceModel.dataListArray?[section].optionsModelArray.count ?? 0
        // return self.questionsModelArray?[section].optionsModelArray.count ?? 0
    }

    func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> NH_OptionsModel{

        print(datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.section].optionsModelArray[indexPath.row])


        return datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.section].optionsModelArray[indexPath.row]

    }
```

didselect tableview:-

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

        if questionViewModel.isselected == true{

            let selectedIndexPathAtCurrentSection = questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.filter({ $0.section == indexPath.section})
            for indexPath in selectedIndexPathAtCurrentSection {
                tableview.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

                if let indexOf = questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.index(of: indexPath) {

                    questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.remove(at: indexOf)

                    let questionModel = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.section)

                    questionViewModel.question = questionModel.question

                    questionViewModel.insertQuestList(answer: questionViewModel.question!, Index: indexPath.section)


                    let c = questionModel.answerType
                    print(c)
                    let cellClass = c?.cellType().getClass()
                    print(cellClass)
                    let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? BaseCell
                    print(cell)

                  //  let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NH_QuestionListCell


                    questionViewModel.button = questionModel.buttontype

                    let value: Int = questionModel.id

                    let string = String(describing: value)

                    questionViewModel.question_id = string

                    questionViewModel.question = questionModel.question

                    let model = questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)


                    if questionModel.buttontype == "2" {
                        questionViewModel.insertStrng(answer: model.values!, Index: indexPath.section)
                        cell?.setOptions(OptionsisSelected:questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))

                    }

                    else if questionModel.buttontype == "1"{
                        questionViewModel.insertStrng(answer: model.values!, Index: indexPath.section)
                        cell?.setOptions1(OptionsisSelected:questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))
                    }

                    questionViewModel.isselected = model.isSelected!
                }
            }

            questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)

            let questionModel = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.section)
            let c = questionModel.answerType
            print(c)
            let cellClass = c?.cellType().getClass()
            print(cellClass)
            let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? BaseCell
            print(cell)
            let model = questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)

            if questionModel.buttontype == "1"{
                questionViewModel.insertStrng(answer: model.values!, Index: indexPath.section)
                cell?.setOptions(OptionsSelected:questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))

            }

            else if  questionModel.buttontype == "2"{
                questionViewModel.insertStrng(answer: model.values!, Index: indexPath.section)
                cell?.setOptions1(OptionsSelected:questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))
                //   }
                print(questionViewModel.answers1)
            }



            questionViewModel.isselected = model.isSelected!


            questionViewModel.question = questionModel.question

            questionViewModel.questionlist(answer: questionViewModel.question!)

            questionViewModel.insertQuestList(answer: questionModel.question, Index: indexPath.section)

            let value: Int = questionModel.id

            let string = String(describing: value)

            questionViewModel.question_id = string

            questionViewModel.question(answer: questionViewModel.question_id!)

            questionViewModel.questIdList(answer: questionViewModel.question_id!, Index: indexPath.section)

            questionViewModel.button = questionModel.buttontype


        }

            // False condition

        else if questionViewModel.isselected == false{


        let questionModel = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.section)

        questionViewModel.question = questionModel.question

        questionViewModel.insertQuestList(answer: questionViewModel.question!, Index: indexPath.section)


        let c = questionModel.answerType
        print(c)
        let cellClass = c?.cellType().getClass()
        print(cellClass)
        let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? BaseCell
        print(cell)
        let model = questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
        print(model.values)


        if questionModel.buttontype == "1"{
            questionViewModel.insertStrng(answer: model.values!, Index: indexPath.section)
            cell?.setOptions(OptionsSelected:questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))
              print(questionViewModel.answers1)
        }

            //Radio Button

        else if  questionModel.buttontype == "2"{

            questionViewModel.insertStrng(answer: model.values!, Index: indexPath.section)
            cell?.setOptions1(OptionsSelected:questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))
            //   }
            print(questionViewModel.answers1)
        }

        questionViewModel.isselected = model.isSelected!

        let value: Int = questionModel.id

        let string = String(describing: value)

        questionViewModel.question_id = string
        questionViewModel.question(answer: questionViewModel.question_id!)

        questionViewModel.questIdList(answer: questionViewModel.question_id!, Index: indexPath.section)

        questionViewModel.button = questionModel.buttontype

        questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)

        }

    }
```

Comment: How to solve the issues?

Comment: table view is reusable cell so you need to store which indexPath button is checked or not. you should  check button is check or not inside cellForRowAt method

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya i know the tableviewcell is reusable cell.But i not understand how to store based on the indexpath is checked or not.how to check inside the cell for rowat in the tableview .Can u show ?

Comment: how to do?how to solve can show where need the changes in the code.

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya can u please show?

Comment: Please give me (model  = questionViewModel's) Atributes

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya i have added my model and viewmodel,please check....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your model object value is update on button clicked event and you need to update cell ui in Cell at index.

Here is reference code for how to update ui at cell at index. 
Note: Code is not checked in xcode so may be some minor error.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let model = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.section)
        print(model.answerType)

        print(model.answerType?.rawValue)

        let c = model.answerType
        let cellClass = c?.cellType().getClass()
        print(cellClass)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: (cellClass?.cellReuseIdentifier())!, for: indexPath) as! BaseCell
        print(cell)

        let optionModel = questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
        cell.setOptions(Options1: optionModel)
          if optionModel.isSelected {
             cell.setOptions1(OptionsisSelected:optionModel)
          } else {
             cell.setOptions(OptionsisSelected:optionModel)
          }

        cell.type = c?.cellType()
        currentCell(c: cell, index: indexPath.row)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Kathrodtiya.I have added my didselect method .please check.As i put your code i got ,but while scrolling up the data is going.How to fix it?

Comment: What is the problem .please can u please help me?

Comment: can u show where is error.I am in confusion ,how to solve the problem?please help me